# Why is Nil required at the end of a list built using the cons operator

Tags: scala

I'm learning Scala at the moment (Programming Scala, 2nd Edition, Odersky).

When building a list using the cons operator we have to write:

```
val l = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: 4 :: Nil
```

Why do we need that Nil at the end? Why can't the compiler understand that 4 is the last element and so just write this instead:

```
val l = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: 4
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The signature of `::` is roughly:

```
case class ::[E](hd: E, tl: List[E]) extends List[E]

// which generates this automatically:

object :: {
    def apply[E](hd: E, tl: List[E]): ::[E]
}
```

The signature of `Nil` is roughly:

```
object Nil extends List[Nothing]
```

As you see, `::` takes an element and a list. `4` is not a list, while `Nil` is.

Comment: So it must be building the list starting with 4 :: Nil, 3 :: ( 4 :: Nil ) and so on?

Comment: Correct.  Operators starting with a colon (:) are right associative in Scala, basically to support exactly this use case.

Comment: I think this answer is confusing in mentioning the `::` case class. It's the `::` method that is relevant in the question.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge the factory method is automatically generated because `::` is a case class, but I will clarify it.

Comment: There is a factory method, but it can't be used in this way. You're actually using the `::` defined in `List`, which is `def ::[B >: A] (x: B): List[B] = new scala.collection.immutable.::(x, this)`

Answer (score 4):

In concept, a List in Scala is either

- a Nil (means an empty list) or
- a head element and tail, which is a List again.

`::` is to create a new list with a head element and a tail list. And it is right associative.

So

```
1 :: 2 :: 3 :: 4 :: Nil
```

will be compiled as

```
1 :: (2 :: (3 :: (4 :: Nil)))
```

Starting from the right, the first list is constructed with 4 and Nil, making a new list [4]. Then adding 3 as the head of the tail list [4], making a new list [3, 4]. And so on...

To answer your question, Scala needs an empty list to construct the 1st list. Cause that's how the list is defined in Scala.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can make it work yourself:

```
scala> implicit class Listable[A](val value: A) {
     |   def ::[B >: A](other: B): List[B] = other :: value :: Nil
     | }
defined class Listable

scala> val xs = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: 4
xs: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> val ys = "A" :: "B" :: "C"
ys: List[String] = List(A, B, C)

scala>
```