# Runtime Exception during executing a function

Tags: scala, runtimeexception, nosuchelementexception

I am trying to run a function in scala

```
 def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = xs match {
  case Nil => throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException("Minimum number of elements")
  case x :: xs => x + sum(xs)
}
```

When I try to run like this,

```
sum(List(1,2,3))
```

I am getting the runtime exception

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Minimum number of elements
  at .sum(<console>:12)
  at .sum(<console>:13)
```

On the other hand, this works

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = xs match {
case Nil => 0
case x :: xs => x + sum(xs)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List(1,2,3)` is equivalent to `1::2::3::Nil`

so your function is evaluated in following order

```
sum(1::2::3::Nil) = 1 + sum(2::3::Nil)
sum(2::3::Nil) = 2 + sum(3::Nil)
sum(3::Nil) = 3 + sum(Nil)
```

and at last `sum(Nil)` throws exception.

You can get more information from following question.

[Why is Nil required at the end of a list built using the cons operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22881671/why-is-nil-required-at-the-end-of-a-list-built-using-the-cons-operator)

[Why do we need Nil while creating List in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37741565/why-do-we-need-nil-while-creating-list-in-scala)